# Create matrix of row-wise increasing differences based on vector

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix

I have a column vector in MATLAB and am trying to construct a matrix of differences with row-wise varying size of difference.

It is hard to explain in words, so I will illustrate with an example:

lets say my data is:

```
data = [ 1 2 3 4 5 6 ];
```

what i am trying to do, is make a matrix that takes the differences as such (each column difference size changes [increasing by one]):

```
diff = 
[(2 - 1) ...
 (3 - 2) (3 - 1) ...
 (4 - 3) (4 - 2) (4 - 1) ...
 (5 - 4) (5 - 3) (5 - 2) (5 - 1) ...
 (6 - 5) (6 - 4) (6 - 3) (6- 2) (6 - 1)]
```

My best guess of doing this was to make a triangle matrix with nested loops. My MATLAB code looks like this:

```
differences = zeros(length(data) - 1, length(data) - 1);
step = 0;  

for j = 1:1:size(data) - 1; 
    for i = 1:size(logquarterly) - 1 - step;

        if j <= i;
        differences(i,j) = data(i + 1 + step , 1) - data(i,1);
        step = step + 1;
        end

    end
end
```

What I am trying to do is calculate the first column of differences with distance 1, then calculate the second column of differences with distance 2 and so on... To accommodate the necessary row values I need, I am using the "step" variable which is set to zero for calculating column one, I then want it to increase by 1 when calculating column 2 to have the correct dimensions. But I can not make it work. If I take the "step" out and use this:

```
differences = zeros(length(data) - 1, length(data) - 1);


for j = 1:1:size(data) - 1; 
    for i = 1:size(logquarterly) - 1;

        if j <= i;
        differences(i,j) = data(i + 1 , 1) - data(i,1);
        end

    end
end
```

everything works, but each column has the same distance of differences and it does not increase by one. Any ideas guys?

Comment: What exactly is that `logquarterly`? Why not write down the final expected values for the given sample input? If the expected output is to be a 2D array, and it seems there would be blank spaces, what should be the fillers for those spaces? Maybe use somthing random instead of 1,2,3,4,5,6 as the input elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your solution is that it will only work with column vectors, because of the loop `j = 1:1:size(data)-1`. The call of `size` will return `[1,6]`; then the -1 is applied yielding `[0,5]`. Then only the first value of this vector is taken and in turn the for loop will only run from `1` to `1-1==0`, i.e. NOT.
Use `numel` or `size(.,1)`/`size(.,2)` instead. (Also don't use semicola `;` after the loop initialization). (Try out the MATLAB debugger!)

Here is my take on how to repair your approach:

```
differences = zeros(length(data)-1, length(data)-1);
for j = 1:size(differences,2) 
    for i = j:size(differences,1)
        differences(i,j) = data(i+1) - data(i-j+1);
    end
end
```

---

I like the use of `gallery('circul',n:-1:1)`, in *thewaywewalk*'s answer, I do however find the rest a bit too complicated.

Here is my take reusing his idea:

```
n = numel(data);
L = ndgrid(2:n,2:n);           % // Generate indices for Left side of operator
R = gallery('circul',1:n-1).'; %'// Generate indices for Right side of operator
out = tril(data(L) - data(R))  % // Do subtraction of corresponding indices
```

Comment: I kind of was overthinking this, for very large arrays (n > 5000) your approach is also a little faster. My upvote you already had ;)

Comment: @thewaywewalk: I really liked the use of `gallery('circul')`, as I had never seen it, so I just *had* to give it a try myself. :-)

Comment: @knedlsepp the gallery function offers a lot other possibilities. Unfortunately the documentation is really bad and unless you know the mathematical background of all testing functions it's hard to just browse and use them.

Comment: @thewaywewalk: Exactly my thought after having a short glance at `doc gallery`.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand right, you want to do that:

```
data = [ 1 2 3 4 5 6 ];
n = numel(data);

%// calculate differences
diffs = bsxfun(@minus, data(end:-1:1), data(end:-1:1).')  

%'
%// get linear indices from circulant sub-indices for rows and 
%// linear indices for columns
idx = sub2ind([n n], gallery('circul',n:-1:1), ndgrid(1:n,1:n))

%// mask output and get lower triangular matrix
output = tril(diffs(idx(n-1:-1:1,n-1:-1:1)))
```

so the output is:

```
output =

     1     0     0     0     0
     1     2     0     0     0
     1     2     3     0     0
     1     2     3     4     0
     1     2     3     4     5
```

Comment: This doesn't run for me. Are you sure your last command is `flip`? Shouldn't it be `flipud` or `fliplr`?

Comment: @kkuilla `flip` is possibly not available in older versions of matlab, have a look at my edit

Comment: Nice trick with `gallery`  I did not know about this function +1